# Nodejs versioning on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have updated node version on ubuntu server. After updating it says now using version v12.13.0 but nodejs -v shows older version v7.0.1. I have tried managing with nvm and run command nvm use 12.13.0 still it shows v7.0.1. I have restarted the terminal and logged again using ssh but nothing change. Please provide suggestion on how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Remove and reinstall it will be helpful!

Comment: @HayTrần still getting v7.0.1

Comment: You might be having two node versions installed, could you show the output of `$ type -a node nodejs`

Comment: Yes there were two nodes running one with node and one with nodejs. There was some issue with symlink I guess. I've solved it by using node with latest version.